# how can i list subtasks list in react?

Tags: reactjs

Hello there everybody i'm working on react application i did list the first activities cards but in the second level i got some problemes this is the error that i got [image]

and before adding this line    < TaskList task={this.state.data.activities.tasks}/> it was fine

[image]

this is my code here the app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DataList from './DataList.js';
import TaskList from './TaskList';
import Ranger from './header.js';
import View from 'react-flexbox';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        activities: [
          {
            id: 'A1',
            label: 'Activite 1',
            tasks: [
              {
                id: 'A1.T1',
                label: 'Activite 1 task 1'
              }
            ]
          }, {
            id: 'A2',
            label: 'Activite 2'
          }, {
            id: 'A3',
            label: 'Activite 3'
          }, {
            id: 'A4',
            label: 'Activite 4'
          }
        ]

      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <View column>
          < View column>
            <Ranger/>
            < DataList data={this.state.data.activities}/>
            < TaskList task={this.state.data.activities.tasks}/>
          </View>
        </View >
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is the tasklist js file

//----------------taskList.js-------------

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Task from './Task.js';
import View from 'react-flexbox';
class TaskList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View column>
                <View row>
                    < View column>
                        <div>
                            {this
                                .props
                                .task
                                .map(task => <Task key={task.id} {...task}/>)}
                        </div>
                    </View>
                </View >
            </View >
        );
    }
}

export default TaskList;
```

//--------------Task.js--------------

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import View from 'react-flexbox';

class Task extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="cardesign">
                {this.props.id}
                <div>
                    {this.props.label}</div>
                <button onClick={this.props.delEvent}>Delete</button>
            </div>

        );
    }
};

export default Task;
```

Comment: Try to set a default value for `this.state.data. activities.tasks`, e.g. `[]`.

Comment: this.state.data.activities is an array from your data in constructor. doing this.state.data.activities.tasks will give undefined as tasks are not in activities

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this.state.data.activities.tasks` because `this.state.data.activities` is an array and has therefore no attribute called `tasks`. You have to get through every activity and then call your task.

```
{
    this.props.activities.map(activity => {
        return activity.tasks.map(task => <Task key={task.key} task={activity.task} />)
    }).reduce((prev, cur) => prev.concat(cur), [])
}
```